# How to coexists shared-lock and exclusive lock in mysql last detected deadlock

Tags: mysql

MySQL version is 8.0.28 and I use Azure Database for MySQL.
A few days ago, there was a dead lock on my MySQL.
But LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK is a Strange.

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2022-09-27 06:58:16 140549605340928
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2321025122, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 38432, OS thread handle 140420189800192, query id 2952713567 20.200.250.225 vicgameserver updating
UPDATE user SET
            play_accum_sec = CASE WHEN play_accum_stime_unix = 0 THEN play_accum_sec ELSE play_accum_sec + v_now_unix - play_accum_stime_unix END, -- 중지된 경우 기간 업데이트 X
            play_accum_stime_unix = CASE WHEN play_accum_stime_unix_dup = 0 THEN 0 ELSE v_now_unix END,
            play_accum_stime_unix_dup = 0,
            curr_server_uid = curr_server_uid_dup,
            curr_server_uid_dup = 0
            WHERE usn = in_usn

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 67 page no 306059 n bits 144 index PRIMARY of table `gamedb_2`.`user` trx id 2321025122 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 40; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 800000003c89341b; asc     < 4 ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00008a580039; asc    X 9;;
 2: len 7; hex 01000007d2017f; asc        ;;
 3: len 12; hex 565757463430323635383139; asc VWWF40265819;;
 4: len 5; hex 64756d6d79; asc dummy;;
 5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 6: len 4; hex 800f4634; asc   F4;;
 7: len 4; hex 800f6a7d; asc   j};;
 8: len 4; hex 633297fe; asc c2  ;;
 9: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;
 10: len 4; hex 63329a6e; asc c2 n;;
 11: len 4; hex 80002071; asc    q;;
 12: len 4; hex 800004a3; asc     ;;
 13: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 14: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 15: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 16: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 17: len 4; hex 80000703; asc     ;;
 18: len 8; hex 8000000063329f01; asc     c2  ;;
 19: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 20: len 4; hex 633297fe; asc c2  ;;
 21: len 4; hex 63329f01; asc c2  ;;
 22: len 4; hex 8869044f; asc  i O;;
 23: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 24: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 25: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 26: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 27: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;
 28: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;
 29: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 30: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 31: SQL NULL;
 32: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 33: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 34: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 35: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 36: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 37: len 8; hex 153cbfa8fa8e175d; asc  <     ];;
 38: len 8; hex 153cbfa8fa8e175d; asc  <     ];;
 39: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 67 page no 306059 n bits 144 index PRIMARY of table `gamedb_2`.`user` trx id 2321025122 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 40; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 800000003c89341b; asc     < 4 ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00008a580039; asc    X 9;;
 2: len 7; hex 01000007d2017f; asc        ;;
 3: len 12; hex 565757463430323635383139; asc VWWF40265819;;
 4: len 5; hex 64756d6d79; asc dummy;;
 5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 6: len 4; hex 800f4634; asc   F4;;
 7: len 4; hex 800f6a7d; asc   j};;
 8: len 4; hex 633297fe; asc c2  ;;
 9: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;
 10: len 4; hex 63329a6e; asc c2 n;;
 11: len 4; hex 80002071; asc    q;;
 12: len 4; hex 800004a3; asc     ;;
 13: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 14: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 15: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 16: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 17: len 4; hex 80000703; asc     ;;
 18: len 8; hex 8000000063329f01; asc     c2  ;;
 19: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 20: len 4; hex 633297fe; asc c2  ;;
 21: len 4; hex 63329f01; asc c2  ;;
 22: len 4; hex 8869044f; asc  i O;;
 23: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 24: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 25: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 26: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 27: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;
 28: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;
 29: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 30: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 31: SQL NULL;
 32: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 33: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 34: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 35: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 36: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 37: len 8; hex 153cbfa8fa8e175d; asc  <     ];;
 38: len 8; hex 153cbfa8fa8e175d; asc  <     ];;
 39: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2321025662, ACTIVE 3 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 9 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 37506, OS thread handle 140482921105152, query id 2952728238 20.200.250.225 vicgameserver updating
UPDATE user SET
        play_accum_sec = CASE WHEN play_accum_stime_unix = 0 THEN play_accum_sec ELSE play_accum_sec + v_now_unix - play_accum_stime_unix END, -- 중지된 경우 기간 업데이트 X
        play_accum_stime_unix = v_now_unix
        WHERE usn = in_usn

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 67 page no 306059 n bits 144 index PRIMARY of table `gamedb_2`.`user` trx id 2321025662 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 40; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 800000003c89341b; asc     < 4 ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00008a580039; asc    X 9;;
 2: len 7; hex 01000007d2017f; asc        ;;
 3: len 12; hex 565757463430323635383139; asc VWWF40265819;;
 4: len 5; hex 64756d6d79; asc dummy;;
 5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 6: len 4; hex 800f4634; asc   F4;;
 7: len 4; hex 800f6a7d; asc   j};;
 8: len 4; hex 633297fe; asc c2  ;;
 9: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;
 10: len 4; hex 63329a6e; asc c2 n;;
 11: len 4; hex 80002071; asc    q;;
 12: len 4; hex 800004a3; asc     ;;
 13: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 14: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 15: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 16: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 17: len 4; hex 80000703; asc     ;;
 18: len 8; hex 8000000063329f01; asc     c2  ;;
 19: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 20: len 4; hex 633297fe; asc c2  ;;
 21: len 4; hex 63329f01; asc c2  ;;
 22: len 4; hex 8869044f; asc  i O;;
 23: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 24: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 25: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 26: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 27: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;
 28: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;
 29: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 30: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 31: SQL NULL;
 32: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 33: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 34: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 35: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 36: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 37: len 8; hex 153cbfa8fa8e175d; asc  <     ];;
 38: len 8; hex 153cbfa8fa8e175d; asc  <     ];;
 39: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 67 page no 306059 n bits 144 index PRIMARY of table `gamedb_2`.`user` trx id 2321025662 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 40; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 800000003c89341b; asc     < 4 ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00008a580039; asc    X 9;;
 2: len 7; hex 01000007d2017f; asc        ;;
 3: len 12; hex 565757463430323635383139; asc VWWF40265819;;
 4: len 5; hex 64756d6d79; asc dummy;;
 5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
 6: len 4; hex 800f4634; asc   F4;;
 7: len 4; hex 800f6a7d; asc   j};;
 8: len 4; hex 633297fe; asc c2  ;;
 9: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;
 10: len 4; hex 63329a6e; asc c2 n;;
 11: len 4; hex 80002071; asc    q;;
 12: len 4; hex 800004a3; asc     ;;
 13: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 14: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 15: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 16: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 17: len 4; hex 80000703; asc     ;;
 18: len 8; hex 8000000063329f01; asc     c2  ;;
 19: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 20: len 4; hex 633297fe; asc c2  ;;
 21: len 4; hex 63329f01; asc c2  ;;
 22: len 4; hex 8869044f; asc  i O;;
 23: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 24: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 25: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 26: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 27: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;
 28: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;
 29: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 30: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 31: SQL NULL;
 32: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 33: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;
 34: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 35: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 36: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 37: len 8; hex 153cbfa8fa8e175d; asc  <     ];;
 38: len 8; hex 153cbfa8fa8e175d; asc  <     ];;
 39: len 8; hex 0000000000000000; asc         ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Trx_Id 2321025122 is Holding X-Lock in row
Trx_Id 2321025662 is Holding S-Lock in row

I don't understand coexists Shared-Lock And Exclusive-Lock in same rows.

Comment: The two locks are not on the same row, that would not be possible.

Comment: heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD is SAME  in Trx 2321025122  AND Trx 2321025662 
This mean is same rows  in Trx 2321025122  AND Trx 2321025662 ??

Comment: All 4 sections (holding locks & waiting for locks) are the same across the two transactions, which does not make much sense. I doubt that the output is the correct one.

Comment: Could you give the table and index definition via `show create table gamedb_2 ` ?